# Php, mysql join and count records

Tags: php, mysql, counter

For some reason I cant make this work:

I have two tables. First called tasks:

```
id     name         project_id     list_id
==========================================
1      First Task   1              1
```

And second one is called Lists:

```
id    project_id     name          position
===========================================
1     1              My List       1
2     2              Second List   2
```

and here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  tl.*,
  COUNT(t.id) AS total 
FROM
  lists AS tl 
  LEFT JOIN tasks AS t 
    ON tl.id = t.list_id 
WHERE tl.project_id = 1
ORDER BY tl.position;
```

and no matter what I always end up with total 0

here is resulting array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [project_id] => 1
            [name] => My List
            [position] => 1
            [total] => 0
        )

)
```

the value of `[total] => 0` should be  `[total] => 1`

Comment: For me your sql query works, i guess you have to post your table create sql commands seems problem can be there

Comment: did you try it in phpmyadmin? if it works, then maybe the problem is in your "PHP" query that you tagged as but no code to support the tag.

Comment: Hold on here, `COUNT(t.id)` shouldn't that be `COUNT(tl.id)`?

Comment: I've got to admit: `t` and `t1` makes it so much harder to even try helping you...

Comment: @FirstOne Well, OP seems to probably be only responding to answers, rather than us *peasant commenters*.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad I had  wrong ID all this time. IT works fine now.

Comment: wrong ID.. ok.. being what *exactly?*

Comment: this part "WHERE tl.project_id = 1"

Comment: so, *what* should it have been then?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yeah, not that uncommon, unfortunately. I've seen people leave their question as is, even after many answers.. I'm guessing the OP should post an answer with the fix and some explanation or delete the question.. or something like that?

Comment: @FirstOne The amount of time we spend is absolute madness at times just waiting and waiting in order to help out. Imagine (*and I'm sure you know this just as well as I*) that on each question and waiting on someone for up to 10 minutes multiplied by 6, that's an "hour" of our time. I'm not really saying this for this OP, but Lordie... it's as if we're their *Personal butlers/valets* or something. I'm the one that should be slapped silly cross-side the head *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh boy if I know. If there is something to take from it is that we shouldn't be going too deep in the rabbit hole. Sometimes you just need to turn the _whatever_ state _on_ and, well, move on.

Comment: @FirstOne Many a time (lately), I turn on my *"5 minute span of attention"* button. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was using incorrect ID in Where clause. It was hard coded to,1 and it should have been dynamic, acquired from URL.